# Simple Matlab GPU

Tags: matlab, gpu

I'm trying to do what I think has got to be the most basic GPU operation imaginable, in Matlab, and I can't seem to figure it out.

I have a list of a million 3D coordinates and I want to find their distance from a single other point.  The core is a simple square root of sum of squares function "getDist(a,b)" where a and b are 3x1 vectors.

Without GPU I could brute force like this:

for x = 1:1e6
  d(x) = getDist(points(:,x),point)
end

If I didn't mind wasting memory I could use repmat to repeat my single point over and over, and I think that would work for GPU:

pointsGPU = gpuArray(points);
pointGPS = gpuArray(repmat(point,1,1e6));

d = sqrt(sum((pointsGPU - pointGPU).^2)));

This is slower than on the CPU.  I narrowed it down to the problem that .^2 is slow on the GPU for some reason.  Basically, I broke the line above into individual parts (the subtraction, square, sum and sqrt.  All were almost 10x faster on GPU, but .^2 was slower.  Multiplying the array by itself with .* took the same time on CPU and GPU.

I tried using arrayfun:

d = arrayfun(@(x) getDist(points(:,x),point), 1:1e6)

but this gives an error with the GPU:  "gpuArray output type is not currently implemented".  I take this to mean that it wants the GPU array to be where the 1:1e6 is, not embedded in the function.  I can't figure out how to formulate it that way since I want to take columns at a time, not single elements.

This HAS to be solvable.  What's a GPU for if not to solve massively parallel geometry problems...  Thanks for any help.

Comment: Why would you NOT compare this to a simple use of bsxfun, rather than using loops as the base case?

Comment: The loop isn't the base case, just an example.  If I do d = sqrt(sum((pointsGPU - pointGPU).^2))) with and without GPU, GPU is slower.  As for bsxfun, I wasn't aware of it and I don't know how to apply it to this problem.  It looks like it wants to given a matrix out, not a vector.

Comment: You may want to read through [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16943670/accelerating-matlab-code-using-gpus)